# Heuristics for blokus game

Tags: search, a-star, heuristics

A variant of the blokus game, where you are a single player and you want to cover all corners of the given board using A* Search, I'm trying to figure out what kind of heuristics would be good for this, so for example on an 8x8 board it would finish fast, without expanding too many nodes.

I want an admissible heuristic, so far I've ruled out:
Manhattan distances and euclid distances because in blokus you need to put pieces adjacent to other pieces diagonal which doesn't comply with manhattan distance.

Information about the game:
It's a board game, in which there is a n x n table, and you are given pieces of sizes and shapes like tetris in which you can put on the table.

The rules are: Each piece is only usable once, and you start from coordinate (0,0). You can only place pieces adjacent to another piece diagonally. Two pieces cannot be adjacent to each other, only diagonally.

The task is to finish game with the lowest score possible (score is determined by how many tiles your pieces are composed with), you want to leave the board as vacant as possible.

Comment: I think you should explain how this game works if you want someone to help you out with the heuristic function.

Comment: I've added an explanation